Not able assign React query fetched data to nested array (nothing but table Row) in react with Typescript app
The live code example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=muitable.tsx
The following code has issue where i need to set Api fetched data to nested array

    await mutateAsync(
      { dataWithDisplayOrder },
      {
        onSuccess: (responseid: any) => {
          //  i got response as id
          setResponseId(responseid);
          // here restting the nestedArray
          resetField('nestedArray');

          // now here i'm passing this id to to fetch the saved details using useeffect
          setResponseId(responseid);
          **// here is my ask ???????
          /// My asK here is how to set fetched data to nestedArray??? to display in UI**
        },
        onError: (error) => {},
      }
    );
  };


how to set Api fetched data to nested Array??? to display in UI

using append method

You need to take a step back and read React Query's docs or a guide to its basics. In your file reactquerysave.tsx, you are trying to pass a mutationKey into useQuery(), but a Mutation and a Query are two different things. Have a look at this series of articles https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query
